# How to convert string to data with 32 bytes count in iOS Swift 3.1

Tags: ios, swift, aes, nsdata, encode

How to convert string to data or NSData with 32 bytes count in iOS Swift 3.
I have a key like this:

```
let keyString = "hpXa6pTJOWDAClC/J6POVTjvJpMIiPAMQiTMjBrcOGw="
```

and test this code for convert to Data:

```
let keyData: Data = keyString.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!  
let keyLength = keyData.count //44
```

key length is 44.
I need convert with 32 because valid key bytes count should be equals: 16 or 24 or 32 base on this cases:

```
let validKeyLengths = [kCCKeySizeAES128, kCCKeySizeAES192, kCCKeySizeAES256]
```

Comment: your key string has length 44.

Comment: `String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)` is the same as `String.Encoding.utf8`

Comment: ... or in this context, just `.utf8`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded string, and [`Data(base64Encoded:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1410081-init)
can be used to decode it, that gives exactly 32 bytes:

```
let keyString = "hpXa6pTJOWDAClC/J6POVTjvJpMIiPAMQiTMjBrcOGw="

if let keyData = Data(base64Encoded: keyString) {
    print(keyData.count) // 32
    print(keyData as NSData) // <8695daea 94c93960 c00a50bf 27a3ce55 38ef2693 0888f00c 4224cc8c 1adc386c>
}
```

Depending on where the string comes from, you might want to add
the `.ignoreUnknownCharacters` option in order to ignore unknown 
characters (including line ending characters), as suggested by
@l'L'l:

```
if let keyData = Data(base64Encoded: keyString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) { ... }
```

Comment: In addition  `options:NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters` can be used with in the case there's anything like a new line character at the end of the string, otherwise it's an error.

Comment: @l'L'l: Yes, depending on where the string comes from that might be useful. You can shorten it to `options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters`.

Answer (score 0):

The function below will give you a 32 byte block of data generated from your key string. As you are using the AES keys length from the Common Crypto library I assume you have access to the rest of the library and CC_SHA256() will be available to you

```
static func sha256Hash(_ string: String) -> Data? {
    let len = Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    let data = string.data(using:.utf8)!
    var hash = Data(count:len)

    let _ = hash.withUnsafeMutableBytes {hashBytes in
        data.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
            CC_SHA256(dataBytes, CC_LONG(data.count), hashBytes)
        }
    }
    return hash
}
```